# Converting a for loop into list comprehension

Tags: python, python-2.7, list, for-loop, list-comprehension

```
airports = [['BCN','Barcenlona'],['DUB','Dublin']]

code = raw_input().upper()

for i in airports:
    if i[0] == code:
        print i[1]
```

I've been able to loop through the 2D Array using the following:

```
[i[0] for i in airports for i[0] in i]
```

However, Is it possible to achieve the same effect using list comprehension by which a user's code e.g. BCN would output Barcenlona?

Comment: A Dict would be more appropriate in this scenario and much faster

Comment: @thatrockbottomprogrammer Oh, Okay - For the purpose of this task I'm required to use a 2D array in a list form unfortunately.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A dictionary *is* the way to do things.

```
In [332]: airports = [['BCN','Barcenlona'],['DUB','Dublin']]

In [333]: dict(airports)
Out[333]: {'BCN': 'Barcenlona', 'DUB': 'Dublin'}

In [334]: mapping = dict(airports)

In [335]: mapping.get('DUB')
Out[335]: 'Dublin'
```

Convert the array to a dictionary, and use either dict indexing with `[]`, or `dict.get` (does not throw `KeyError`s).

The advantage of a dictionary is that it is idiomatically more suited to your data, and facilitates constant, `O(1)` time lookup for values, which is ideal if repeated searches is a use case with your data.

---

If you must use a 2D array, you can try and make this as efficient as possible using `next`:

```
next((y for x, y in airports if x == code), 'Not Found')
```

`next` can accept two arguments -

1. a generator comprehension (any iterator)
2. a default argument that is returned if the iterator does not return anything

Here's a quick sample:

```
In [336]: next((y for x, y in airports if x == 'DUB'), 'Not Found')
Out[336]: 'Dublin'

In [337]: next((y for x, y in airports if x == 'XXX'), 'Not Found')
Out[337]: 'Not Found'
```

Without the default argument, `next` would throw a `StopIteration` with an invalid key:

```
In [338]: next(y for x, y in airports if x == 'XXX')
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
StopIteration                             Traceback (most recent call last)
```

Keep in mind that you cannot escape the `O(N)` complexity pitfall without a dictionary.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in @thatrockbottomprogrammer's comment, a dictionary would be better. But if you still want to use a list comprehension, you can do this:

```
airports = [['BCN','Barcenlona'],['DUB','Dublin']]

code_request = raw_input().upper()

# for i in airports:
#     if i[0] == code:
#         print i[1]

results = [city for (code, city) in airports if code == code_request]
```